# Media queries do not seem to be working

Tags: html, css, grid, media

I'm trying to add a media query to my page but it doesn't seem to work

I'm still new and don't completely grasp how media queries work yet

Here's the code for the media query:

```
@media screen (max-width:320px){h1{font-size:0.75em;}h1{font- 
size:0.8em;}p{font-size:0.8em;}figcaption{font-size:0.8em;}.img-style{max- 
width:45px;max-height:45px;}#profile-link{max-width:55px;max- 
height:55px;}#navbar{text-align:center;}}
```

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/don0ts/pen/JByjqO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write like this: "@media only screen and" instead of "@media screen"

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) { wrap styles inside  }  , on width smaller than 320px it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, just delete "screen" from "@media screen".

```
    @media (max-width:320px){
      h1{
        font-size:0.75em;
      }
      h1{
        font-size:0.8em;
      }
      p{
        font-size:0.8em;
      }
      figcaption{
        font-size:0.8em;
      }
      .img-style{
        max-width:45px;max-height:45px;
      }
      #profile-link{
        max-width:55px;max-height:55px;
      }
      #navbar{
        text-align:center;
      }
  }
```

Or you can change to "@media only screen and (max-width:320px)".

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `and` word off.

```
@media screen 
and (max-width: 320px) {

  //styles go here

}
```

Comment: might i ask what are the "only' & "and" for?

Comment: the `only` was for older versions of IE but isn't needed now.  The `and` word is  needed because it's part of the syntax so your media query won't work without it.